# Bcrypt hashes common part

Tags: java, spring, bcrypt

I have a hash created by bcrypt (using [spring bcrypt password encoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html)) from a user password. I need to generate a key based on this hash so that next time the user enters his password application would create a hash from it and then generate the same key. The problem is that using bcrypt I get different hash each time for the same password. I wonder if there is something common in all hashes generated by bcrypt for a string. Could I extract some common and constant part from the hashes to create a key from it?

Comment: You're doing something wrong if you're not getting repeatable hashes with bcrypt, and what you're trying to do sounds like you need a KDF anyway.

Comment: What library do you use for creating the bcrypt hashes? Can you supply the salt? If you can supply the salt you could re-use the salt from the existing hash. But why would you need to get the same hash?

Comment: @chrylis, different hashes each time is the way how the library works.

Comment: Why do you need the same hash each time? You should only need to hash it the first time (presumably to save into a database) and then use `matches` on other attempts (against the saved hash).

Comment: @vstm, updated the question.  The salt is randomly generated inside encode() method and I don't know what value it has. I need to add some encrypted data for users and decided to use password hash as encryption key so that users don't have to enter its passwords to encrypt the data explicitly. But I can't use stored in db hash as a key because next time user enters his password the library will generate different hash from the same password and application won't be able to decrypt the data using new hash as the key

Comment: @Chung: thank you for the clarification. Ok so your library is pretty restricted and you can't define the "salt", so that's why you get new hashes every time. But that's a good thing, since this is what makes the bcrypt hashes secure. I'm not sure why you need to make your passwords as keys. You should always have a username or the e-mail address as a key and then load the user by that key (not the password). And if you have loaded the user you need to verify the password with the `matches` method.

Answer (score 0):

Investigated [BCrypt.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.java) which is used by the library and found that a salt is embedded into resulting hash. And the library extracts it during password verification in `matches` method, generates the same hash using the salt and then compares the generated hash with the one that was provided. 
Knowing the salt I can get the same hash, as @vstm mentioned in comment.